# Type 'RegExp' is not defined. RegEx = New RegExp

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have the following code:

```
<script runat="server">
Function NameName(strText)
    Dim RegEx
    RegEx = New RegExp
    RegEx.Pattern = "<[^>]*>"
    RegEx.Global = True
    NameName = RegEx.Replace(strText, "")
End Function
```

And I get the error: error BC30002: Type 'RegExp' is not defined.  RegEx = New RegExp

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If this is meant to be server-side ASP.NET code, you have to use .NET's `Regex` class:

```
Function NameName(strText As String) As String
    NameName = Regex.Replace(strText, "<[^>]*>", String.Empty)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! That cleared the error, but now it is giving a new one:  error BC30188: Declaration expected.

    RegEx = New RegExp                                            Here is my code for this line:  

   '------defining script vars-------------------
   Dim mailObj, mailCfg, myBody, fld, subj, mail_from, mail_to, smtp_server, smtp_port, plain_text

 Dim RegEx 
    RegEx = New RegExp

Comment: @Winona `Dim RegEx RegEx = New RegExp` is not valid syntax (`RegEx` appears two times instead of one) and `RegExp` is not a valid class either (same problem as your initial question)